# Printing every N columns in new file

Tags: text-processing, split

How to print every 100 columns of a file with 1000 columns in 10 different files?
`split` command is use to split rows into different files. I am looking for columns in different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` and `cut`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for i in {0..9}; do
    let start=i*100+1
    let end=i*100+100
    cut -d ' ' -f ${start}-${end} file.txt >file_$i.txt
done
```

Comment: This works great..!!!

Answer (score 2):

If the file isn't *too* large, then one option might be to transpose, split, and then transpose the result e.g. if you have GNU `split` with the `--filter` option

```
rs -T < somefile | split -l100 --filter='rs -T > $FILE'
```

Illustrating with a more manageable sized input

```
$ printf 'A B C D E F G H I J\n0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\na b c d e f g h i j\n' | 
    rs -T | split -l2 --filter='rs -T > $FILE'
```

Then

```
$ cat xaa
A  B
0  1
a  b

$ cat xae
I  J
8  9
i  j
```

Comment: maybe you need to have a loop or use `find` to process this on all _files_ as OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` alone.

```
awk '{i=0; split($0, arry, / +/); 
    for (x in arry) {
        if ((x%100)==1)i++; printf (x%100)?arry[x]FS:arry[x]"\n" >"FILE_"i
    }
}' in_multiple_files
```

Simple 40columns input and with `x%10` instead:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20 c21 c22 c23 c24 c25 c26 c27 c28 c29 c30 c31 c32 c33 c34 c35 c36 c37 c38 c39 c40
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN
```

Result in 4 files.

```
==> FILE_1 <==
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
A B C D E F G H I J

==> FILE_2 <==
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20
K L M N O P Q R S T

==> FILE_3 <==
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
c21 c22 c23 c24 c25 c26 c27 c28 c29 c30
U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD

==> FILE_4 <==
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
c31 c32 c33 c34 c35 c36 c37 c38 c39 c40
AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN
```

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -v n=100 '{ r=""; 
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
                    f=sprintf("%s%s",$i,(!(i%n))?"":OFS); 
                    r=(r!="")? r OFS f : f; 
                    if (!(i%n)) { print r > FILENAME"_"++c; r="" } 
                } 
                c=0 }' file
```

---

- `-v n=100` - adjustable splitting coefficient
- `r=""` - initialized resulting string
- `!(i%n)` - determining the moment when the record should be split on filed number multiple of coefficient `n`